# SQL Parse Duration String to Seconds

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 12.0.4213.0 and am new to advanced SQL queries.

I have a `nvarchar` column named **duration** containing timespans in one of two formats: `39 Seconds` if the duration is under 1 minute, else the format is like `1 Day 18 Hours 2 Minutes`. Note that each Day/Hour/Minute/Second can be singular or plural. Also in the first format, if the day is 0, the Day will be omitted (same with Hour).

I need to convert the duration to an integer representing total seconds. `1 Minute 30 Seconds` should return 90 and `39 Seconds` should return 39.

I think this could be completed with a nested CASE statement. The dataset is very large so I want to be sure I am approaching this efficiently. Any help would be appreciated.

One method I have working in PowerShell is to split the **duration** column on the space character, loop through the resultant array incrementing counter by 2, take `array[counter]` and multiply it by the corresponding seconds value determined by `array[counter+1]`, add the product to the total seconds sum.

Comment: It should be possible to achieve what you want using string functions.  But why suffer such pain when you can avoid it?  Store your timestamps as...timestamps instead of `nvarchar`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I agree with you, however I am not an admin for this DB and am strictly a consumer of the data.

Comment: What if it's just 2 minutes. Does it say 0 days 0 hours 2 minutes?

Comment: @scsimon - for 2 minutes, it says "2 Minutes". For 4 days, it says "4 Days".

Comment: Is it always in the same order? I mean, can you get `3 Seconds, 4 Minutes`? Also, can it be `3 Days 2 Minutes` or if you have days you are always going to have hours as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little complicated, but not terrible. The way you can solve this is by removing the Day(s), Hours(s), Minute(s), Second(s) labels from the string, and replacing these with some delimiting string/character.

Then you can split the resulting values using a CTE.

Then, you'll create the timespan in seconds from each part based on it's location in the delimited string.

Finally, sum over the resulting time-span-part-seconds.

***EDIT:** Now defined as a function*

Like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_getDurationSeconds(@duration varchar(100)) returns int 
as
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @durationSeconds INT = 0;

    with split (duration, part, remainder) as
    (
        SELECT 
            duration,
            left(duration, CHARINDEX(':', duration)-1),
            right(duration, LEN(duration) - CHARINDEX(':', duration))
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        CASE WHEN @duration LIKE '% Day'   or @duration like '% Days'    THEN @Duration + ' 0 Hours 0 Minutes 0 Seconds'
                                             WHEN @duration LIKE '% Hour'  or @duration like '% Hours'   THEN @Duration + ' 0 Minutes 0 Seconds'
                                             WHEN @duration LIKE '% Minute'or @duration like '% Minutes' THEN @Duration + ' 0 Seconds' 
                                             ELSE @Duration
                                        END, ' Day', ':'),
                                    ' Hour', ':'),
                                ' Minute', ':'),
                            ' Second', ':00'),
                        's', ''),
                    ' ', '') duration

        ) t
        union all
        select
            duration, 
            left(remainder, CHARINDEX(':', remainder) - 1),
            right(remainder,  LEN(remainder) - CHARINDEX(':', remainder))
        from split
        where CHARINDEX(':', remainder) > 0 
    )
    SELECT @durationSeconds = sum(seconds)
    FROM 
    (
        select 
            duration,
            CASE row_number() over(partition by duration order by LEN(remainder) ) 
                WHEN 4 THEN 24 * 60 * 60
                WHEN 3 THEN 60 * 60
                WHEN 2 THEN 60
                WHEN 1 THEN 1
            END * CAST(part AS INT) Seconds
        from split 
    ) t
    group by duration
    order by duration


    RETURN @durationSeconds
END
```

Comment: thank you for your response. How would I create a function (eg calcSecs) where I can pass the duration and return the int seconds? In my query, I will need to `SELECT ID, DurationSec=SUM(calcSecs([duration])) .... GROUP BY ID`

Comment: Realized there was a bug in that code (minutes counted as seconds when seconds are unspecified).-- fixed!
I wouldn't recommend using a function here. Functions are a single thread  process, which will slow down your queries. 
My recommendation would be to use this logic in a stored procedure, if possible.

Comment: Just in case you need the function anyway, I updated my answer to be in the form of a function..

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `substring` and `patindex` and a couple of common table expressions to get the desired result:

First, create and populate a sample table: (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Duration varchar(40),
    NumberOfSeconds int
)

INSERT INTO @T (Duration) VALUES
('39 Seconds'),
('2 Minutes 4 Seconds'),
('1 Hours 7 Minutes 17 Seconds'),
('3 Days 9 Hour 8 Minutes 25 Seconds')
```

Then, use one cte to hold the `patindex` results for each word.
This cte is only there to save us the need to write the `patindex` over and over again.
Add another cte to this one, that will use `substring` to extract the values for each time part, using the first cte:

```
;WITH cte1 as
(
    SELECT  *,
            PATINDEX('%Day%', Duration) As DaysIndex,
            PATINDEX('%Hour%', Duration) As HoursIndex,
            PATINDEX('%Minute%', Duration) As MinutesIndex,
            PATINDEX('%Second%', Duration) As SecondIndex
    FROM @T
), cte2 as
(
SELECT  *,

        CASE WHEN DaysIndex > 0 THEN
            CAST(SUBSTRING(Duration, 0, DaysIndex) As int) * 60 * 60 * 24
        ELSE
            0
        END As D,
        CASE WHEN HoursIndex > 0 THEN
            CAST(
            SUBSTRING(Duration, 
                CASE WHEN DaysIndex > 0 THEN DaysIndex + 4 
                ELSE 0 
                END, 

                CASE WHEN DaysIndex > 0 THEN HoursIndex - DaysIndex - 4 
                ELSE HoursIndex 
                END
            ) As int) * 60 * 60
        ELSE
            0
        END As H,
        CASE WHEN MinutesIndex > 0 THEN
            CAST(
            SUBSTRING(Duration, 
                CASE WHEN HoursIndex > 0 THEN HoursIndex + 5 
                ELSE 0 
                END, 

                CASE WHEN HoursIndex > 0 THEN MinutesIndex - HoursIndex - 5 
                ELSE MinutesIndex 
                END
            ) As int) * 60
        ELSE
            0
        END As M,
        CASE WHEN SecondIndex > 0 THEN
            CAST(
            SUBSTRING(Duration, 
                CASE WHEN MinutesIndex > 0 THEN MinutesIndex + 7 
                ELSE 0 
                END, 

                CASE WHEN MinutesIndex > 0 THEN SecondIndex - MinutesIndex - 7 
                ELSE SecondIndex 
                END
            ) As int) 
        ELSE
            0
        END As S
FROM cte1
)
```

Now, update the `NumberOfSeconds` column:

```
UPDATE cte2 
SET NumberOfSeconds = D + H + M + S
```

Verify the update results:

```
SELECT *
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
Duration                                 NumberOfSeconds
---------------------------------------- ---------------
39 Seconds                               39
2 Minutes 4 Seconds                      124
1 Hours 7 Minutes 17 Seconds             4037
3 Days 9 Hour 8 Minutes 25 Seconds       292105
```